# How to prevent flex item from overgrowing its content

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to keep the number of search results in parentheses (2nd flex item) right next to the preceding phrase (1st flex item) when flex container gets stretched but the number (2nd flex item) is pushed to the right:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>flex item being pushed to the right</title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            body > div {
                border: 1px solid silver;
                display: flex;
                margin: 0.5em;
            }
            div > div:first-child {
                flex-grow: 1;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                white-space: nowrap;
                width: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>Search results for "some reasonably long long long long long long long long long long long sentence"</div>
            <div>(6)</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This happens because first flex item has "flex-grow" property set to "1" and it overgrows its content.
I tried to remove "flex-grow", "white-space" and "width" properties and set "line-height" property for flex items to flex container's height in order to hide all the lines but the first one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>2 flex item being pushed to the right</title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            div > div {
                line-height: 32px; /* new */
            }
            body > div {
                border: 1px solid silver;
                display: flex;
                height: 32px; /* new */
                margin: 0.5em;
            }
            div > div:first-child {
                /*flex-grow: 1;*/
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                /*white-space: nowrap;*/
                /*width: 0;*/
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>Search results for "some reasonably long long long long long long long long long long long sentence"</div>
            <div>(6)</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but this way when flex container gets shrinked there is a gap between the phrase and the number as wide as first word being pushed to next (hidden) line and
"text-overflow" property doesn't work either - ellipsis does not appear next to shrinked phrase.

Is there any other way to keep the number of search results always next to preceding phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to set `flex-grow: 1;` and `width: 0;` and everything will work.
Optionally, you can set `min-width` so that the first `div` does not shrink to 0.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body > div {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

div > div:first-child {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 160px; /* optional */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Search results for "some reasonably long long long long long long long long long long long sentence"</div>
  <div>(6)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got flex container like this wrapped in parent div in my project and forgot to set "overflow: hidden" on flex container which caused parent div to overflow which lead me to think it was necessary to set "width: 0" and "flex-grow: 1" on first flex item to prevent parent div from overflowing.